# Monogame. Level depth in various draw functions?

Tags: c#, xna, draw, monogame

In animatedSprite.cs I have:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Vector2 location)
    {
        int width = Texture.Width / Columns;
        int height = Texture.Height / Rows;
        int row = (int)((float)currentFrame / (float)Columns);
        int column = currentFrame % Columns;
         Rectangle sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(width * column, height * row, width, height);
     Rectangle  destinationRectangle = new Rectangle((int)location.X, (int)location.Y, 120, 140);
        if (Game1.przelacznik_w_bezruchu == true) { sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height); }
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, destinationRectangle, sourceRectangle, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();}
```

In GameScene.cs

```
 private void DrawGame(){
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(floor1, rec_floor1, color1);
    spriteBatch.Draw(floor2, rec_floor2, color1);
    spriteBatch.Draw(house1, rec_house1,color1);
    spriteBatch.End();}
```

I want the floor and the house to be on a lower level than the sprite, so that they do not obscure the sprite. But I dont know how to assign depth levels to textures.

Comment: Please don't use answers to ask questions, Just add a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have multiple batches, defined as the code between `spriteBatch.Begin()` and `spriteBatch.End()`.

By default, `spriteBatch.Begin()` is called with no parameters, all sprites are drawn in the order they are called: the first draw call is the background. The second draw call will be on top of the first...

As @ProfessionalKent stated in his answer use the `layerDepth` parameter:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, destinationRectangle, sourceRectangle, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, layerDepth);
```

layerDepth accepts any `float` value(the default is 0), **Lower values are rendered on top of higher values**. Any identical values are done in the order entered.

This parameter also applies to `spriteBatch.DrawString()`

**However, `layerDepth` is only valid within the same batch.**  Once `End()` is called the batch is sorted, flattened and rendered to the frame buffer.

### Solution

Write down the required depths for all of the drawn objects. Replace the `layerDepth` numbers in the following code to reflect your analysis.

Remove all `spriteBatch.Begin()` and `spriteBatch.End()` lines in your entire project. Unless `spriteBatch.Begin()` has non [default](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/blob/3f472703e0116d1532f1cb71de886e8c75121271/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/SpriteBatch.cs#L93)(Lines 81 and 91-100) parameters.

In `Game1.cs` open the spriteBatch as early as possible after `GraphicsDevice.Clear`:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
   GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

   spriteBatch.Begin();

   // Your existing code here.

   spriteBatch.End();

   //oprozniony, nothing should be here
}
```

In GameScene.cs:

```
private void DrawGame()
{
// The ,, is for the null source rectangle, 
    spriteBatch.Draw(floor1, rec_floor1,, color1, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, 2);
    spriteBatch.Draw(floor2, rec_floor2,, color1, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, 3);
    spriteBatch.Draw(house1, rec_house1,,color1, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, 1);

// example of a table the animatedSprite(at a depth of 0) will walk or move behind(note the negative depth):
//    spriteBatch.Draw(stol, rec_stol, , color1, 0.0f , Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, -1);

}
```

In AnimatedSprite.cs

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Vector2 location)
    {
        // unless the width and height can change when the game is running, they should be class variables set in the constructor
        int width = Texture.Width / Columns;
        int height = Texture.Height / Rows;

        // removed unnecessary casts:(unless currentFrame is not an int)
        int row = currentFrame / Columns;
        int column = currentFrame % Columns;
        Rectangle sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(width * column, height * row, width, height);
        Rectangle destinationRectangle = new Rectangle((int)location.X, (int)location.Y, 120, 140);
        if (Game1.przelacznik_w_bezruchu == true) sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);

// Place the sprite at Depth of 0.
        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, destinationRectangle, sourceRectangle, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, 0);        
}
```

There are situations that will require multiple batches. If that is the case, split the batches by depth order manually.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload for the SpriteBatch Draw function that allows you to specify layerDepth.

You would use the following in your Draw call for animatedSprite.cs:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, destinationRectangle, sourceRectangle, Color.White, 0.0f, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, layerDepth);
```

layerDepth would be a float value which allows you to control the sorting order for your sprites. This could be passed in from your GameScene.cs as a float parameter or you could change the location parameter to a Vector3 and use its Z variable.

As far as the other paramaters:

- 0.0f is the rotation value (on the Z axis) for the sprite
- Vector2.Zero is the "origin" parameter, which allows you to control the rotation point for your sprite. This is useful to rotate around a point other than the top left (usually the center)
- SpriteEffects.None This keeps your draw call the same as in your original post. Different SpriteEffect values allow you to do things like flip the texture horizontally or vertically.